# Moving tftpboot folder

Tags: centos, redhat

Ok, so I am trying to move the `/var/lib/tftpboot` folder the "proper" way to a dedicated partition. To accomplish this goal I have setup a separate partition called `/app` and moved the tftpboot folder there.

Issue 1: Symlink
After I moved the folder I created a symlink from the new directory to the old directory using the `ln -s /app/tftpboot /var/lib/` command. After doing this I am unable to successfully restart the service using `systemctl restart tftp`. However, if I just update the path listed in the service file and the config file the service boots fine.